# How to make click on div element trigger ajax call in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have div element in my view and I want it to trigger ajax call on mouse click (Rails way).

I've read in [documentation (see 3.2.2)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) that you just have to set data attributes and it should work, but its not.

This is not working:

```
<div class="room" data-remote="true" data-method="get" data-url="<%= url_for([:backend, @restaurant, room]) %>"><%= room.name %></div>
```

If I'm using link_to function it works perfectly:

```
<%= link_to 'test link', [:backend, @restaurant, room], remote: true %>
```

Can't find any solution on the internet... Will be very happy if someone can answer this.

EDIT:

Also this is working correctly:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-remote="true" data-url="<%= url_for([:backend, @restaurant, room]) %>" />
```

Comment: When you do `rake routes` Is the route it is hitting a `get` route?  What type of request is getting sent on the one that works, is it a `get` request or something else?

Comment: @RockwellRice yes it is a get route. Checkbox example is working with and without data-method attribute.

Comment: @MaticJan did you find any way to make it work?

Comment: @alexventuraio no, it only works on specific elements out of the box. I haven't used rails for awhile now, so it might be different for newer versions.